# "Not my preference", "not my favour" or "not in my favour"?

Tags: synonyms, phrase-meaning

I'm considering the following situation:

> *A* asks *B* whether *B* would like to take the Job *X*. But *B* actually prefers another Job *Y*.

So I think that *B* can simply answer that "Job *X* is not my **preference**."

My question is: Can *B* also answer that "Job *X* is not my **favour**."? Are "not my preference" and "not my favour" of the same meaning?

A follow-up question is: How about "not **in** my favour"? Which roles can these three ("preference", "favour" and "in sb's favour") play in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that favour is being used in your example is obsolete:

> 1 d. The object of favour; a favourite. Obsolete. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68695?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=APwluF&)

What you mean to say is that "Job X is not my *favourite*," which is to say, it is not my preferred choice out of a list of choices.

> B 1 a. (adj.) Regarded with especial favour, liking, or preference; beloved, **chosen, favoured above others**. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68708?rskey=wcSelT&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

"Job X is not my preference" is awkward, and you would do well to say "I prefer Job Y" or "Job X is not my top/preferred choice."

Without going into all the ways that favour operates as a noun, when you say "it's my favour," it would mean one of two things:

That you are doing a service for someone for no charge: "It's my favour" (read: gift; it's free)

> 2 b. n. something conceded, conferred, or done out of special grace or goodwill; an act of exceptional kindness, as opposed to one of duty or justice [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68695?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=APwluF&)

or that you are giving someone a token of affection or mark of favour:

> 7 a. n. (concrete of 1.) Something given as a mark of favour; esp. a gift such as a knot of ribbons, a glove, etc., given to a lover, or in mediæval chivalry by a lady to her knight, to be worn conspicuously as a token of affection. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68695?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=APwluF&)
>
> 7 b. n. A ribbon, cockade, or the like, worn at a ceremony [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68695?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=APwluF&)

Not in my favour would imply that you did not get the job: "The result was not in my favour" (read: someone else was selected). Similarly, in court, if the judge decides for you, you can say that "The decision was in my favour."

> 6 b. n. To the advantage of [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68695?isAdvanced=false&result=1&rskey=APwluF&)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion! I have found out (by google) the reference for the second quote but not the first, could you show me that? And I have seen a couple of examples, they use "favour" as "with ... favour". So I wonder whether it's also normal to use "favour" without any preposition but just e.g. "it's my favour."

Comment: OED is the Oxford English Dictionary. There is an online version at oed.com, but you may find it paywalled.

Comment: @larkvi You should still link to it, and give a citation in the form they want.

Comment: @larkvi Unfortunately the OED is paywalled and I can't access it. So if we go through all the ways that "favour" operates as a noun, would there be a possibility that "it's not my favour" is a correct reply in our situation? And would it be a usual colloquial way to say "it's not my favour"?

Comment: @Salomo I realize it is paywalled, which is why I quoted it to you. I have already clearly indicated that "It's not my favour" is wrong in your situation, and would not be a usual colloquial way to say that in any dialect I am aware of. I have provided usual and suitable alternatives which anyone would understand; I suggest you use "It's not my favourite (job offer)." or "It is not my preferred (job offer)."

If you prefer to see the whole entry and do not have access to a physical OED, try American Heritage: https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=F5056800

Answer (score 0):

> Not my favour

This usage of favour means *the state of being approved or held in regard: to be in favor at court; styles that are now in favor.* [Favour](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/favour)

> My question is: Can B also answer that "Job X is not my favour."? Are "not my preference" and "not my favour" of the same meaning?

B could answer like this, and the meaning would be similar, although slightly archaic, so it may be better to expand it to '*not my favoured option*', or to be less ambiguous '*Not my preferred option*'.

---

> A follow-up question is: How about "not in my favour"?

This means that there is no advantage to it (and possibly even a disadvantage, when compared with another option) which is not the same as preference.

*When something is in your favour, it gives you an advantage:
This candidate has a lot in her favour, especially her experience of teaching*. [Favour](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favour)

Comment: But according to the your link, the meaning of favour (without prep. "in") can be: (i) the support or approval of something or someone; (ii) a kind action that you do for someone. So I find it strange to say that "Job X is not a support" or "Job X is not a kind action." It seems to have great difference from "preference."

Comment: @Salomo *Not my favour* is used in the sense *Job X does not have my support/approval* thus *it is not my favoured option*. Have updated answer to show source for this meaning

Comment: So would you mean that we can use "not my favour" in this situation but the meanings of "not my preference" and "not my favour" are essentially different?

Comment: I'm saying that *not my favour* and *not **in** my favour* are two different meanings. The first is preference, the second is advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see that "my favour" and "in my favour" are hugely different. Now I want to make it clear whether there is any (subtle) difference between "preference" and "favour", or they are totally equivalent. I hesitate because it seems that "favour" has a meaning of support (or kind act) but "preference" doesn't. "Preference" seems to express something that I like.

Comment: @Salomo Using *preference* would remove any ambiguity about the meaning of favour

Comment: This answer does not address the question as posed.